# Hide show divs with mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I want to be able for this not to show the comments div on load, When click comments I then want it to open the comments div.

How do I do this? I have looked around but...All i get from reading about when put in action it will only work for the one div which obvs the content div results for each post and separate comments as you can see in the code.

```
<?

$data = mysql_query("SELECT `i`.*, `a`.* FROM `Wall` `i` LEFT JOIN `WallComments` `a` ON (`i`.`ID` = `a`.`Comments_ID`) WHERE `i`.`Username` = '{$view}'");

while($Comments = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ 

$walldate = gmdate('g:i a j F, Y', ($Comments['WallDate']));
$postdate = gmdate('g:i a j F, Y', ($Comments['Date']));

        echo
        "<div id='Wall'><a class='menuLink' href='Profile.php?view={$Comments['MessageBy']}' onclick='return false;'>{$Comments['MessageBy']}</a> - On: {$walldate}<br />Wrote: {$Comments['Message']}</div><br /><br />

<div id='Wall'><br />Comments<br /><br />{$Comments['CommentUsername']} Commented - On: {$postdate}<br />Wrote: {$Comments['Post']}</div><hr><br />

        ";
      }
      ?>
```

Every time  a user makes a post it inserts new row in database and same for comments so I need it to auto make the divs sort of thing rather than having div  id=1 div id =2 sort of thing, Which is what I get on everything I look at on the web.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hide the div initially:

```
<div id='Wall' style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Use JavaScript to let the div appear:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('Wall').style.visibility='visible';">
Show
</button>
```

You may include the comments in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('Wall').style.visibility='visible';">
Comments here
</a>
```

Comment: how would I implement the button onclick with the....    <div id='Wall'><br />Comments<br /><br />{$Comments['CommentUsername']} Commented - On: {$postdate}<br />Wrote: {$Comments['Post']}</div><hr><br />

Comment: Is 'Wall' a unique id in the document?, have you tried with different browsers? Is any error logged in the (Firefox) error console?

Comment: Wall is used for both above Just want it to show the word comments once clicked DIV opens displaying the comments.

Comment: obvs the comments come from my database.